# Rewriting a specific URL: adding a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working on a WordPress-site and I have an URL like

```
https://example.com/technische-uebersetzungen
```

What I need is:

```
https://example.com/subdirectory/technische-uebersetzungen
```

My code has a bug, it does not rewrite the URL. I placed it at the end of the existing `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^technische-uebersetzungen/(.*)$ /blog/technische-uebersetzungen/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Does anybody know, what is that bug?

Comment: To clarify, this directive is an external 3xx "redirect", not an internal "rewrite", as you have described in the text. (_Aside:_ You cannot rewrite the URL in `.htaccess` when using WordPress.)

Answer (score 0):

> My code has a bug, it does not rewrite the URL. I placed it at the end of the existing `.htaccess` file.

One "bug" is placing that rule at the end of the `.htaccess` file. By placing the rule *after* the WordPress code block, the request is first rewritten to `index.php` and your rule is never processed.

This "redirect" needs to go at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress code block (ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker).

> ```
> RewriteRule ^technische-uebersetzungen/(.*)$ /blog/technische-uebersetzungen/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
> ```

This rule matches `/technische-uebersetzungen/<anything>` (note the mandatory trailing slash after the first path segment) and the `<anything>` part is copied onto the end of the target URL. This is not mentioned in your example.

Your example URL is for `/technische-uebersetzungen` exactly (no trailing slash). And nothing is appended to the end of the target URL.

Try the following instead at the *top* of the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^technische-uebersetzungen(/.*)?$ /blog/$0 [R=301,NC,L]
```

This will match `/technische-uebersetzungen` or `/technische-uebersetzungen/<anything>` and redirect to the same URL with a `/blog/` prefix.

NB: You must test this first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid any potential caching issues and only change this to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed this works as intended.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: @rabo What do you mean by "does not work" exactly? Do you get an error? An undesirable redirect? Nothing?? What happens when you request `https://example.com/technische-uebersetzungen`?